# Animation of function

Tags: python, animation

[image]

Trying to solve this problem for my Python class. He gave us some sample code from a similar problem, but when I enter the new equation I can't get it to work. Any help with what is wrong?

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_fun(ax,x,t):
    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(x,y,lw=2)
    ax.set_xlim([-1,1]), ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
    ax.set_xlabel('x'), ax.set_ylabel('f(x,t)')

# Prepare the figure container and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

# Prepare the 1D Domain: x from -1 to 1.
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)

# Plot the function at t=0
t = 0
y = (1/(1+16(x-t)**2))
plot_fun(ax,x,t)
plt.show()

# Animation function
tfin = 1
k = 0.1
while t < tfin:
    t = t + k 
    y = (1/(1+16(x-t)**2))
    plot_fun(ax,x,t)
    plt.draw()
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

In two places change

```
y = (1/(1+16(x-t)**2))
```

to

```
y = (1/(1+16*(x-t)**2))
```

---

Take note of the error message:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

which hints that an `int` was treated like a callable (i.e. a function). Python sees `16(x-t)` and thinks the int object `16` is being called (because an object followed by parentheses indicates the object is being called).

Also take note of the line on which the TypeError is raised:

```
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/script.py", line 31, in <module>
    y = (1/(1+16(x-t)**2))
```

This is a big hint as to where to look for an integer followed by parentheses.

---

Note also that the code calls `plot_fun(ax,x,t)` and yet `plot_fun` uses `y`, not `t`. That looks like a logical error...

---

By the way, matplotlib comes with an [`animation` module](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/index.html) which can make animating plots a little easier.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
t = 0
y = (1/(1+16*(x-t)**2))
line, = ax.plot(x, y, lw=2)
ax.set_xlabel('x'), ax.set_ylabel('f(x,t)')
tfin = 1
k = 0.1
ts = np.arange(0, tfin, k)

def animate(i):
    t = ts[i]
    y = (1/(1+16*(x-t)**2))
    line.set_data(x, y)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, interval=100, frames=len(ts), repeat=True)
plt.show()
```